# access main class attributes from sub class callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

Javascript code 
i want to use this.progressbar inside media callback function

```
  class CatMusicPlayer {

  constructor(url,playPauseBtn,progressbar,progressTime,durationTime) {
    this.url = url;
    this.playPauseBtn = playPauseBtn;
    this.progressbar = progressbar;
    this.progressTime = progressTime;
    this.durationTime = durationTime;

    new Media(url,null,this.logerror,function(mediaStatus){

        /*
            i want to use this.progressbar,
            but in this block "this" reffers to Media class.
            Media is kind of another class similar to CatMusicPlayer
        */

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

cache value of `this` to another variable like `const _thisMP = this;`
 and later use it `_thisMP.progressbar();`

or in your case, you can even directly call `progressbar()` as it is accessible

```
class CatMusicPlayer {

  constructor(url,playPauseBtn,progressbar,progressTime,durationTime) {
    this.url = url;
    this.playPauseBtn = playPauseBtn;
    this.progressbar = progressbar;
    this.progressTime = progressTime;
    this.durationTime = durationTime;
    const _thisMP = this;

    new Media(url,null,this.logerror,function(mediaStatus){
       _thisMP.progressbar(); // call here

        /*
            i want to use this.progressbar,
            but in this block "this" reffers to Media class.
            Media is kind of another class similar to CatMusicPlayer
        */

    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you :). this was simple. i just got into loop of finding the other way out.

thank you :) it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

```
class CatMusicPlayer {

  constructor(url,playPauseBtn,progressbar,progressTime,durationTime) {
    this.url = url;
    this.playPauseBtn = playPauseBtn;
    this.progressbar = progressbar;
    this.progressTime = progressTime;
    this.durationTime = durationTime;
    let self = this;
    new Media(url,null,this.logerror,function(mediaStatus){
       self.progressbar();


    });
  }
```